# What is a way to solve for the argument of the absolute value of the natural exponential function?

Tags: exponential-function, absolute-value

I’d like to solve for $x$ in the equation:

$y = \lvert e^{-icx}\rvert$

where $x$ and $y$ are real constants and $c$ is a complex number of the form $a+ib$. Recognizing that the modulus of a complex number is the square root of the sum of the squares of the real and imaginary parts, I’ve tried to expand the equation in terms of sines and cosines but got stuck. Any ideas?

Comment: $|e^{-ixc}|=|e^{-ix(a+ib)}|=|e^{-ixa}\cdot e^{xb}|= |e^{-ixa}|\cdot |e^{xb}|= e^{xb}$, since $|e^{i u}|= 1$ for all $u\in \mathbb R$ by Euler's Formula. Therfore $x= \frac{\ln y}b$.

Comment: In terms of your sines and cosines, the hint would be that $\sin^2 + \cos^2 = 1$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please don't assign tags if you don't know what they mean.  This question has nothing to do with algebraic geometry, a very advanced subject.

Comment: @Desperado, that's it! Thank you for the solution. Why post as a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: @saulspatz - thank you for the correction. My account was restricted from creating new tags.

Comment: @rumbleB. I have added it  as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

$|e^{-ixc}|= |e^{-ix(a+ib)}|= |e^{-ixa} \cdot e^{xb}|=
|e^{-ixa}| \cdot |e^{xb}|= e^{xb}$, since
$|e^{iu}|=1 $ for all $u\in \mathbb R$ (Euler's formula). Therefore,
$x= \dfrac{\ln y}b$.